# JUnit to retrieve value from database to test criteria

Tags: junit5

How do I write JUnit with actual service/repository call to retrieve data from a database table instead of using a mock service/repository?

Here the below code returns an empty list of object, whereas I am expecting few hundred objects. `findAll()` is a simple method for which I am trying to write JUnit but later on I will be writing JUnit for a method which takes Map as JSON from request parameters and  forms a criteria API so in this case, I would like to test

> 1. Request
> 2. Parsing of the request in Controller(what controller receives)
> 3. And forming the SQL Criteria and returned object and that's the reason I don't want to mock service/repository.

I am using Spring Boot Rest Controller and for Unit Testing, I am using Mocikito and JUnit.

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(CaDetailController.class)
public class CaDetailControllerTest {

    private static ObjectMapper objectMapper = null;

    private List<CaDetail> caDetails;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc controller;

    @MockBean
    CaDetailRepository repository;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void beforeClass() {
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    }

    @Before
    public void before() {
        caDetails = new ArrayList<CaDetail>();
    }

    @After
    public void after() {
        caDetails = new ArrayList<CaDetail>();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void afterClass() {
        objectMapper = null;
    }

    @Test
    public void getCorporateActions() throws Exception {
        MvcResult result = controller.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/api/ca").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andReturn();
        caDetails = objectMapper.readValue(result.getResponse().getContentAsByteArray(), new TypeReference<List<CaDetail>>() {
        });
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>> caDetails : " + caDetails);
        assertNotNull(caDetails);
        assertTrue(caDetails.size() > 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write integration test for your services which will directly communicate with database. For example go through this link.
http://www.springboottutorial.com/integration-testing-for-spring-boot-rest-services